# What is a scope for lambda function in C++11 (delegates)

Tags: c++11, lambda, delegates, scope

I'm currently working on a GUI for my C++11/OpenGL3.3 project and I though about making some kind of callback system for interactive GUI elements. I used JS/jQuery and I really liked system of definig in-place methods like onMouseOver, onClick for each website element i wanted. I found that delegates are the best way for me to get such feature.

**Example code:**

```
class Button {
    public:
        // ...

        // method (not needed in real-life, just to "show" it)
        void MouseOver(int x, int y) { onMouseOver(this, x, y); }

        // variable
        std::function<void(Button*, int, int)> onMouseOver;
}

void someFunction(...) {
    // ...
    Button t = new Button(...);
    t.onMouseOver = [](Button* this, int x, int y) -> void { some_code_here };
    // ...
}
```

**Main question:**

But i'm worried about scope of that particular onMouseOver function that i just created - will that pointer be valid until end of program? Can someone explain what exactly will happen with that function for the rest application lifetime?

**Additional questions:**

Is there a better way to do something like that? Simpler/more efficient? I've seen many "imposible fast" - is it really that slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *What is a scope for lambda function in C++11?*

---

According to the standard *§ 5.1.2/2 & 3  Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]*:

> `2` The evaluation of a lambda-expression results in a `prvalue` temporary (12.2). **This temporary is called the closure object**.
>
> `3` **The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace
>   scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.**

- So according to the above, your Lambda function's scope is the scope of function `someFunction()`.
- However, because you assign it to `onMouseOver` member variable, its move constructor is evoked, consequently `onMouseOver` will hold a moved instance of your Lambda.

---

> *Will that pointer be valid until end of program?*

---

- Class template `std::function` is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper (i.e., a function object). Instances of `std::function` can store, copy, and invoke any callable target (e.g., functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects).
- Consequently, `onMouseOver` and its content will be valid as long as the `Button` class object that contains it is valid.

Comment: @Ripper Yes, think of lambdas as unnamed functions objects, the local instance of lambda is moved in the member variable and consequently its "alive" as long as its object that holds it is "alive".

Comment: I deleted fist comment since edited part of answer covers my question. Thanks for professional answer! :) Last question - is std::function<> good enough (fast) to use it in this project? Or should i look for one of that "super-fast-extra-mega c++ delegates"?

Comment: @RippeR I'm not really an expert on this (i.e., C++ delegates), however there are some good online articles on the subject the most recent I know is http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/2014-01-12-C%2B%2B-delegates-on-steroids.html